# how to dispaly a javascript:popup dialog on top of a overlay to block the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery

iam having a link tag on clicking it gives a another jsp as javascript:popup dialog.i need to block the page behind this popup dialog with a transperant page to diasable the controls on parent page.

this is my link

```
<a href="javascript:popupDialog('<c:url value="/addConfiguration" />', 'configDiv')" >click to add new configuration </a>
```

Comment: Try `value=\"/addConfiguration\"`

Comment: @hjpotter92 That's getting preprocessed out by the jsp engine, so it won't make a difference. If anything, it'll probably cause a parsing exception.

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92.but how to can I block the parent page from being accessed ??

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the bottom of your html just before the closing `</body>` tag. (you can put the css in a different file if you wish, to organize things better).

```
<div id="page-blocker"></div>

<style type="text/css">
    #page-blocker{
        position: absolute;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100vh; /* View-port height */
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.4;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
        display: none;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>
```

Now you can call `$('#page-blocker').show();` to block the page and `$('#page-blocker').hide();` to un-block the page. Use it from within the `popupDialog()` function and the one the hides the Dialog.

**Note:** You might want to set the `z-index` of this blocker to 999, if you have other Absolutely positioned elements on the page. And the z-index of the pop-up to 1999.